# error when Parsing input c

Tags: c, parsing

Hi i am writing a simple c program to test parsing a buffer in c but when i run the program i get the following errors:

```
./test.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.c: line 4: `int main()'
```

Does anyone know why these errors are occurring? 
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char* command;

    char* buf = malloc(100 *sizeof(char));

    buf = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\n Host: www.gla.ac.uk\n";

    command  = strtok(buf, " ");
    printf("%s", command );

    free(buf);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to run source code without compiling. That's not the proper way to do.

First compile the source code

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

Then execute it

```
./test
```

Comment: Good spot.  Just tried it in bash and I get the exact error reported in the question.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
buf = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\n Host: www.gla.ac.uk\n";
```

do not

```
free(buf);
```

I suppose you should do

```
strncpy(buf, "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\n Host: www.gla.ac.uk\n", 100);
```

instead of

```
buf = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\n Host: www.gla.ac.uk\n";
```

And correct mallocing looks like:

```
char* buf = (char *)malloc(100 *sizeof(char));
```

Comment: No, [don't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1606345) in C

Answer (score 0):

You actually want a *copy* of your string, as the string literal you'd like to assign is constant. You can use `strdup`, or probably safer, use `strndup` to make a copy of the string. This does implicitly use malloc, so you should `free` it afterwards.